# Flexbox вёрстка. Margin

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox, navigationbar

1) Пытаюсь сверстать navbar на flexbox, на float-ах было бы проще сделать то, что я хочу, но стараюсь всё делать именно на flexbox. Так вот, вопрос: можно ли как-то переместить отдельный элемент в правый угол его контейнера? Но сделать это на flexbox и при этом дополнительно его ни во что не оборачивать. Здесь мне нужно элемент "item" переместить вправо, в конец. И да, почему над "HOME" есть чёрные отступы, он должен быть на полную высоту.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2) Думал отодвинуть его на margin-left, но было бы правильно это делать, или если это сделать, и задать конкретное кол-во пикселей, то у разных мониторов будет выглядеть по-разному? И какими единицами измерения лучше пользоваться? Читал, что "px" лучше не надо.

```css
.header, .topnav {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: black;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}

.topnav a:hover {
   background-color: #ddd;
   color: black;
}

.topnav a {
 font-size: 20px;
 color: white;
 padding: 10px;
}

#active {
 background-color: green;
}

.icon {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="topnav">
   <a href="#" class="hrefs" id="active">Home</a>
   <a href="#" class="hrefs">News</a>
   <a href="#" class="hrefs">Contacts</a>
   <a href="#" class="hrefs">About</a>
   <b><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="openCity()">&#9776;</a></b>
  </div>
 </header>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можете задать свойство flex-grow для контейнера, обрамляющего последний элемент списка, и выровнять текст по правому краю.

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
li a {
  color: white;
}
.active {
  background-color: #5DB97D;
}
.menuBurger {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ul class="topnav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li class="menuBurger"><a href="#">menu</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Сначала не получалось, как Вы сказали, но потом оказалось, что передвигаться ему мешал тег <b>, я то думал он ничего не решает, просто жирнее текст делает, а он выступил неким контейнером для "icon". Большое спасибо Вам!

Comment: Ссылки мелкие :(

Answer (score 1):

```css
.header, .topnav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

#active {
  background-color: green;
}

.topnav a:last-child {
  order: 2;
}

.topnav:before {
  content: "";
  flex: 1 0 0px;
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="topnav">
    <a href="#" class="hrefs" id="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#" class="hrefs">News</a>
    <a href="#" class="hrefs">Contacts</a>
    <a href="#" class="hrefs">About</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Да, маржином слева как раз можно, просто напишите margin-left: auto;
Насчет полоски у меню - у Вас все items находятся по центру, и высота блока НОМЕ не растягивается, а такая, как есть, либо напишите align-self: stretch; либо добавьте паддингов, или с высотой поиграйтесь.

Comment: Спасибо, большое, помогло!)